# how to access "this" object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

How come in the code below, the second line is giving me an undefined error?

```
function DAO()
{
        this.arrVariable = new Array();
        this.getItem = getItem;
        this.getItemQuery = getItemQuery;
}

function getItem(key)
{
        dao.arrVariable[key]();
}

function getItemQuery(key, url, options, pollfrequency)
{
        alert('hey');
}


var dao = new DAO();
dao.arrVariable['var1'] = function() { this.getItemQuery('a','b','c','d'); };

dao.arrVariable['var1']();
```

I want to be able to access the dao's getItemQuery as an object call.  How do I do this?

Comment: Why do you need to use "this"?  My assumption is that getItemQuery actually does more than alert 'hey'? Perhaps you could elaborate?

Comment: The DAO object will have many more properties.  I'd like to be access them when I'm in the `function() {this.getItemQuery}`

Comment: Refer to Michael's answer "this" is not needed for what you are doing.

Comment: Since `dao.addVariable` is declared as an array, do you really intend to add the object property `var1` to it? In JavaScript, syntax like `arrVariable['var1']` refers to an object property, _not_ an array key.

Comment: Just as an aside, if you want an "associative array", i.e., you want to access elements based on key names rather than numeric indexes, then you should be using a JavaScript object: `x = {}; x["key1"] = "A";`

Comment: Where's your second line? The `{` won't throw an error. Did you mean the last line throwing an error, which occured in the function declaration?

Comment: Just a minor thing, but `this.arrVariable = new Array();` should be written as `this.arrVariable = [];`, as it is preferable to use array literals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that context, `this` refers to `arrVariable`. You can instead refer to it as `dao.getItemQuery()` inside the function:

```
dao.arrVariable['var1'] = function() { dao.getItemQuery('a','b','c','d'); };
```

Comment: To be exact, `this` refers to `dao.arrVariable`, not to the property `var1` (which would be the function itself)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) here.

So, instead of

```
dao.arrVariable['var1']();
```

Use either

```
dao.arrVariable['var1'].apply(dao, /* array of arguments here */);
```

or

```
dao.arrVariable['var1'].call(dao, /* arguments here, separated by commas */);
```

Answer (score 1):

dao.getItemQuery can access dao's property

Answer (score 0):

THe this in `function() { this.getItemQuery('a','b','c','d'); };`  refers to function() not to DAO.  You need to access DAO by:

```
dao.arrVariable['var1'] = function() { dao.getItemQuery('a','b','c','d'); };
```

Comment: No, `this` refers to the object the function is called on. This might be the array in Johns secont-to-last line, or the window object if the function is called "directly".